# django rest framework set image field to null when updating the field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my code;

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{ self.title } - { self.author }"
```

serializer.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class BookListViews(generics.ListAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

The object is created alright, but when I try to update the title or author field, without updating the image, once I post it, the image value is set to null. This is problem because, I don't want to keep changing the image or update the image anytime I want to change the title or author field.

Comment: it's because you're sending cover_image: null in the payload probably. Just don't send that property in your PUT/PATCH

Comment: As @Trent said, its most likely a problem with your `request.data`